# UIActionSheet Crashing when using XCode 5

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uiactionsheet

in an iphone app I was displaying a simple UIActionSheet and it was working correctly on XCode 4.6 and now I want to migrate the app to XCode 5.

But when I moved to XCode 5, the app is crashing when showing the Action sheet.

I am using an iPhone 4 with ios 7 to test on both

This is my action sheet code (I removed most part of it to try to narrow down the issue)

```
UIActionSheet *languageMessage = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

languageMessage.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
[languageMessage showInView:self.view];
```

The app is crashing (**SIGABRT**) on this line

```
[languageMessage showInView:self.view];
```

while debugging `self.view` is not null and is read correctly so that is not the issue

This is the stack trace

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x19cd1e, 0x3860f688 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 35.1
frame #0: 0x3860f688 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x30bd8bc6 UIKit`-[UIActionSheet _assertIfValidForView:] + 190
frame #2: 0x30c403b4 UIKit`-[UIActionSheet showInView:] + 164
frame #3: 0x00126cac Bassara`-[RootLoginViewController showLanguageSheet](self=0x165ba810, _cmd=0x00371c48) + 444 at RootLoginViewController.m:84
frame #4: 0x00126ac6 Bassara`-[RootLoginViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x165ba810, _cmd=0x30ffef84) + 774 at RootLoginViewController.m:68
frame #5: 0x309f737a UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 518
frame #6: 0x309f7138 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 24
frame #7: 0x309fde04 UIKit`-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 64
frame #8: 0x309fb4da UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 306
frame #9: 0x30a6608c UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 60
frame #10: 0x30a62e58 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1656
frame #11: 0x30a5d352 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 714
frame #12: 0x309f841e UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3130
frame #13: 0x309f7720 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
frame #14: 0x30a5cb3c UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 664
frame #15: 0x32e9370c GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 608
frame #16: 0x32e932f6 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 34
frame #17: 0x2e24a9de CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
frame #18: 0x2e24a97a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
frame #19: 0x2e24914e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1398
frame #20: 0x2e1b3c26 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
frame #21: 0x2e1b3a0a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
frame #22: 0x30a5bdd8 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 760
frame #23: 0x30a57048 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
frame #24: 0x00044e80 Bassara`main(argc=1, argv=0x27dc3cf4) + 116 at main.m:16

thread #2: tid = 0x19cd41, 0x38bbb83c libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager
frame #0: 0x38bbb83c libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
frame #1: 0x38b06e0c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
frame #2: 0x38af63a2 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 38

thread #3: tid = 0x19cd43, 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #0: 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #1: 0x38c34dca libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 310
frame #2: 0x38c34c84 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 8

thread #4: tid = 0x19cd48, 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #0: 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #1: 0x38c34dca libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 310

thread #5: tid = 0x19cd5c, 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #0: 0x38bcec7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
frame #1: 0x38c34dca libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 310
```

What might be causing the crash on XCode 5 and not on XCode 4.6

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Is there a crash message in the debugger ?

Comment: Works great for me in ios 7 / xcode 5.1. Does your method is not called from the main thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame #3: 0x00126cac Bassara`-[RootLoginViewController showLanguageSheet](self=0x165ba810, _cmd=0x00371c48) + 444 at RootLoginViewController.m:84
frame #4: 0x00126ac6 Bassara`-[RootLoginViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x165ba810, _cmd=0x30ffef84) + 774 at RootLoginViewController.m:68
```

You seem to be creating and showing `UIActionSheet` in `viewDidLoad` method where the view is completely created. There is a fair chance that the `view` referred through `self.view` is not completely created.

You should move the `showLanguageSheet` call to `viewDidAppear` method instead. If you want to display the action sheet only once when view controller get created/displayed then hold a simple `BOOL` flag and set it after displaying action sheet.

Something like,

```
-(void) viewDidAppear {
    if(!isActionSheetShown) {
        [self showLanguageSheet];
        isActionSheetShown = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was the issue.

Comment: @Youssef May not be Xcode related, but iOS version related. Any case, it is hard to know the reason. Better to avoid the issue completely :)